# Finding an original rectangle's dimensions from rotation and bounding box dimensions

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, trigonometry, bounding-box

In AS3, I have a Sprite that has a Z axis rotation applied.

How do I calculate that Sprite's dimensions (it's original size) from Sprite.rotationZ and Sprite.getRect(...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sprite.width` and `sprite.height` on `sprite.rotationZ = 0` would give you the original size.

Comment: Haha! Yeah that's my intermediate hack.

I'd rather do it with the maths though, then I'll have learnt something universal rather than an AVM shortcut...

Comment: Seconds thoughts, it's obviously impossible! You win.

Answer (score 1):

antpaw's answer is best / easiest.  It can also be done without ever seeing it visually if you switch the rotationZ back once you get your width and height, like so

```
var rotZ:Number = mySprite.rotationZ;
mySprite.rotationZ = 0;
var w:Number = mySprite.width;
var h:Number = mySprite.height;
mySprite.rotationZ = rotZ;
```

To do this mathematically you could look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622140/calculate-bounding-box-coordinates-from-a-rotated-rectangle-picture-inside) and do the reverse.

Comment: The typical bounding box edge formula won't reverse because it's missing length plus missing length.

I'm sure there is something that'll look a bit like it though...