# Rotate Bitmap (Rectangle) While Maintining Area

Tags: c#, graphics, rotation, clipping

How can I rotate an Bitmap a given number of degrees while maintaining the area of the original bitmap. ie, what I rotate a bitmap of Width:100,Height:200, my end result will be a bigger image but the rotated portion will still have an area of 100*200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graphics transform function is perfect for this. Create a new bitmap of the size you want, create a graphics object based off that bitmap, apply the transform then draw onto the canvas (graphics.drawimage(original_image)).

Here is a [much better example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/TransformswithGDIplus09142005064919AM/TransformswithGDIplus.aspx) than I can give at this time.

And [Bobpowell.net](https://web.archive.org/web/20130312094930/http://www.bobpowell.net/transformations.htm) is a site I usually reference back to for great explanations on transforms.

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused by this question.  Rotation doesn't change scale, so your rectangle will always be 100 x 200 pixels (within the margin of error caused by bitmap rendering).  Are you asking how to find the minimum bounding box that will hold a 100 x 200 pixel image rotated at an arbitrary angle?  [That's been answered elsewhere on Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622140/calculate-bounding-box-coordinates-from-a-rotated-rectangle-picture-inside)