# Parent wrapper should adopt size as per rotation angle

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, transform

```
<div class="element-wrapper">
<div class="target-element" style="transform: rotate(0.982927rad); width: 148px; height: 46px;">Heading</div>
</div>
```

Before Rotate
[image: before rotate]

After Rotate
[image: after rotate]

As seen in the screenshot. I want to change height and width of "element-wrapper" as per transform angle ( like 2nd screenshot after rotate ).

You can check fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cv53wwo5/)!

Comment: In css you can not do it (complex answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16302202/4771277), you can just use javascript, more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392658/calculate-the-bounding-boxs-x-y-height-and-width-of-a-rotated-element-via-jav