# calculate div width and height of rotated div

Tags: javascript

Can we calculate divs width and height from angle and w and h values shown in the picture ?

[image]

Comment: This might help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392658/calculate-the-bounding-boxs-x-y-height-and-width-of-a-rotated-element-via-jav

Comment: try this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect