# Get a rotated texture width and height

Tags: c#, xna

Well,hi again,i have a question,and this time is about scripting.
To be direct,i'd like to know how i can get width and height of a texture that is rotated on XNA.

Comment: I'd imagine that it's the same width and height of a texture that's not rotated on XNA

Comment: its a trigonometric equation. give me a second to think it up

Comment: Here you go.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231176/how-to-get-size-of-a-rotated-rectangle

Comment: Exactly what i wanted Daniel,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newWidth = textureHeight * Math.Sin(angle) + textureWidth * Math.Cos(angle);
newHeight = textureHeight * Math.Cos(angle) + textureWidth * Math.Sin(angle);
```