# calculate new image size before CGContextRotateCTM

Tags: resize, quartz-graphics, image-rotation

Greetings!

This question is rather mathematical, with the iphone SDK/quartz as example:

I am rotating an image using CGContextRotateCTM:

- Create a new context with the size of
  the source image
- rotate source image and draw it in context
- pass context to new rotated image.

This works fine, but the image is cut off at the edges, because it doesn't fit into the source image size. I would like to resize the context/the resulting image so that the entire rotated image is visible.

What algorithm could I use to calculate the needed size of the context before I start the rotation?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Could you post the code your using, that should help with diagnosing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone passing by:
This post answers my problem:

[Calculate Bounding box coordinates from a rotated rectangle, Picture inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622140/calculate-bounding-box-coordinates-from-a-rotated-rectangle-picture-inside)

Thanks, m