# Bounding box of rotated rectangle

Tags: java, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculate Bounding box coordinates from a rotated rectangle, Picture inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622140/calculate-bounding-box-coordinates-from-a-rotated-rectangle-picture-inside)

How do i calculate a bounding box of a rotated rectangle ?

I have X,Y ( top left ) , width, height, and rotation in degrees and i need to fast calculate minX,minY,maxX,maxY of that rectangle. What is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/622140/544963