# How can I get the height/offset of an element after it has 'skew' transform has been applied with JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quite simply my question is as the title:

Is there any way to get the height of an element after it has had `transform:skew();` applied to it?

e.g. If the height of an element is 100px and the top offset is 500px pre-transform, after having a skew applied to it, the height may actually be 150px and the top offset may actually be 450px, yet the standard height() and offset() methods in jQuery still report the original values.

Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the `height()` and `offset()` are unchanged because they in fact remain unchanged. CSS transforms are mostly just styling, for the DOM the element is still there with its width, height and position. Not sure if it is even possible to access the transformed display's properties.

Comment: Yes that's correct, and while I fully understand it, I had hoped that there was a relatively simple method for retrieving post transformed properties.  I guess that's not the case.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: I also hope that it'd be possible. In fact I've never done throughout research on that. Whenever I need the dimensions of a transformed object I just do the maths that the transform would and get the value. Of course that's not always viable.

Comment: At least that clears it up for me Fabrico.  Thank you.  If you'd like to put your comment into an answer I will mark it as correct.  Perhaps with the suggestion to actually perform the transformation math manually to account for the transform as a potential solution. Cheers.

Comment: Guess it'd be better to leave it open for a day or two, you never know. Webkit has a lot of "hidden" features, that even though not being fully cross-browser, are interesting to investigate. The upcoming Shadow DOM *might* make this easier somehow, even though I doubt that. Still, your question has potential to more than just doing the maths manually. `=]`

Comment: I suppose you could access getComputedStyle, collect the resulting Matrix and perform the math on that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, the values of height and width are unchanged since they are based on the DOM element without styling. However i noticed that the offset() method returns the correct value from a transformed element (Chrome 23 and Firefox 16 OSX).

To give you a solution - for 2d-transforms such as skew and rotate, I did the basic math for the transformation and the following function returns the width and height value based on an elements transformation matrix. This worked for all the 2d-transformations I tried, rotation/skew and combinations of the two (Again, on Chrome 23 and Firefox 16 OSX).

```
function getBoundingBox(element){
    // Get the transformation matrix as a string
    var tm = element.css('transform');

    // Transform the string to an array
    var regexp = /-?\d+[\.\d]*/g;
    tm = tm.match(regexp);

    // Get the size of the object and calculate the bounding box
    var h = element.height();
    var w = element.width();
    var th = Math.abs(h * tm[0]) + Math.abs(w * tm[1]);
    var tw = Math.abs(h * tm[2]) + Math.abs(w * tm[3]);

    return {'height':th,'width':tw}
}
```

[More information and explanations about bounding boxes and calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622140/calculate-bounding-box-coordinates-from-a-rotated-rectangle-picture-inside)