# Rotating a rectangle and calculating the extra space it needs after rotation

Tags: android, geometry, image-rotation

I have two rectangles that are equivalent and lie on top of each other. We might imagine them as a picture and a frame with the exact same dimensions. Now I rotate the picture (around it's middle) while keeping the frame fixed, so that the vertices of the picture slides outside the frame. I would like to calculate how much vertical and horizontal space I need to add to the frame in order to make it big enough to show the rotated picture. I know how much the rectangle is rotated (in degrees) and I know the dimensions of the rectangles.

Here is an illustration (bad drawing, sorry).

[image: rectangles]

The red and the yellow lines are the lengths that I would like to calculate.

The application of all this is an Android program, where I cannot rotate the view itself (due to version problems), but I can rotate the image inside the view. I would still very much like to keep the view exactly large enough to display the image after the rotation.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate Bounding box coordinates from a rotated rectangle, Picture inside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622140/calculate-bounding-box-coordinates-from-a-rotated-rectangle-picture-inside)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let your half sides be `a` and `b`.

If you rotate by `alpha`, the rectangle vertex moves from `(a,b)` to

```
(a*cos(alpha)-b*sin(alpha),a*sin(alpha)+b*cos(alpha))
```

(this is, basically, the complex multiplication).

Thus the red line is

```
a*sin(alpha)+b*(cos(alpha)-1)
```

and the yellow line is

```
a*(cos(alpha)-1)+b*sin(alpha)
```