# How to get the bounding rectangle of rotated rectangle 3D?

Tags: c#, 3d, geometry

I have a 3D rotated rectangle around its center, How can I get the 3D rectangle bounding this rotated rectangle.
I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622140/calculate-bounding-box-coordinates-from-a-rotated-rectangle-picture-inside) to do so but in 2D ; finding min. X and min. Y is not my case in 3D because Z is not always the normal to the rectangle plane.

[image]

Comment: Could you not rotate the rectangle so z is pointing forward then using the same method as in the answer to the question you posted.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko do u mean that i rotate it to align with Z axis then compute my points then rotate them again ? I'll try that, Thanks for the hint :)